# Flex по вверх flex выходит за грань своего родителя?

Tags: css

Почему в данном случае когда изменяется разрешение он выходит за рамки своего родителя ?
Блок со свойством флекс не может работать внутри флекс ?

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.main {
    max-width: 600px;
    display: flex;
  background: #c7c7c7;
}
.l_block {
    width: 50%;
    background: #000;
}
.r_block {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.r_block > div {
    background: red;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
  margin: 10px;
}
div {
      height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;background: green;max-width:800px;height: 400px;"> 

<div class="main">
    <div class="l_block">
        
    </div>
    <div class="r_block">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните суть вопроса: какой блок поверх какого куда выходит?

Comment: @humster_spb, посмотрите зеленый фон это родитель, остальные при сужении экрана выходят за его рамки

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь: зелёный фон у безымянного блока. А родитель для правого и левого - это main

Comment: @humster_spb, я про родителя майна и всего что там есть

Comment: ну так чего Вы добиться-то хотите? чтобы правый блок уходил под левый? задайте main свойство flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: А почему у вас у l_block 50% ширина, а у r_block - 80% ?